# Using streams, how can I map the values in a HashMap?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Given a `Map<String, Person>` where Person has a `String getName()` (etc) method on it, how can I turn the `Map<String, Person>` into a `Map<String, String>` where the `String` is obtained from calling `Person::getName()`?

Pre-Java 8 I'd use

```
Map<String, String> byNameMap = new HashMap<>();

for (Map.Entry<String, Person> person : people.entrySet()) {
    byNameMap.put(person.getKey(), person.getValue().getName());
}
```

but I'd like to do it using streams and lambdas.

I can't see how to do this in a functional style: Map/HashMap don't implement [`Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html).

`people.entrySet()` returns a `Set<Entry<String, Person>>` which I can stream over, but how can I add a new `Entry<String, String>` to the destination map?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

With Java 8 you can do:

```
Map<String, String> byNameMap = new HashMap<>();
people.forEach((k, v) -> byNameMap.put(k, v.getName());
```

Though you'd be better off using Guava's [Maps.transformValues](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html#transformValues%28java.util.Map,%20com.google.common.base.Function%29), which wraps the original `Map` and does the conversion when you do the `get`, meaning you only pay the conversion cost when you actually consume the value.

Using Guava would look like this:

```
Map<String, String> byNameMap = Maps.transformValues(people, Person::getName);
```

**EDIT:**

Following @Eelco's comment (and for completeness), the conversion to a map is better done with [Collectors.toMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-) like this:

```
Map<String, String> byNameMap = people.entrySet()
  .stream()
  .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, (entry) -> entry.getValue().getName());
```

Comment: I'm accepting this as it's so neat, and no tiresome for loops. The Guave solution is particularly neat. Thanks

Comment: @DavidKerr Note that the first code is not parallelisable because HashMap is not thread safe, as opposed to using a collector/toMap which will partition the job if the stream is parallel. Guava's version is not parallelisable either. But if that is not a concern then by all means use this version.

Comment: The first solution is not functional. The other answer, using the toMap collector, is.

Comment: @Eelco agreed, using `Collectors.toMap` is really the way to do this (was only just getting into Java 8 when I answered this)

Comment: It would be nice if we could just do `Map<...> newMap = map.mapValues(mapFunction)`...

Answer (score 28):

One way is to use a `toMap` collector:

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toMap;

Map<String, String> byNameMap = people.entrySet().stream()
                                     .collect(toMap(Entry::getKey, 
                                                    e -> e.getValue().getName()));
```

Comment: That's kinda neat, but is there any advantage to this way over the example cited in the question? I'd say the original example was clearer / more readable code.

Comment: @CharlesGoodwin readability is ok once you get used to it although the for-loop is probably easier to read. One bonus of the lambda is that for a large map you can `entrySet().parallelStream()` and parallelise the job easily. For a simple use case the loop is fine.

Comment: @CharlesGoodwin I guess it will only pay off in terms of readability when you add more filtering and transformations before putting it into the map.

Comment: @asslias: that's a very good point about parallelStream(): something to bear in mind

Comment: @CharlesGoodwin: I agree about the benefit being non-existent with such a simple transformation, but it's interesting to see *how* it can be done

Comment: @CharlesGoodwin I think the readability may be better because it's closer to Java 7 syntax. But it has side-effects as previous commenters noted because it updates the `byNameMap`. In a functional approach, side effects are eliminated.

Answer (score 4):

Using a bit of generic code that I've sadly not found in the libraries I had at hand

```
public static <K, V1, V2> Map<K, V2> remap(Map<K, V1> map,
        Function<? super V1, ? extends V2> function) {

    return map.entrySet()
            .stream() // or parallel
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    Map.Entry::getKey, 
                    e -> function.apply(e.getValue())
                ));
}
```

This becomes essentially the same as Guavas `Maps.transformValues` minus the downsides mentioned by others.

```
Map<String, Person> persons = ...;
Map<String, String> byNameMap = remap(persons, Person::getName);
```

And in case you need the key as well as the value in your remapping function, this second version makes that possible

```
public static <K, V1, V2> Map<K, V2> remap(Map<K, V1> map,
        BiFunction<? super K, ? super V1, ? extends V2> function) {

    return map.entrySet()
            .stream() // or parallel
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    Map.Entry::getKey,
                    e -> function.apply(e.getKey(), e.getValue())
                ));
}
```

It can be used for example like

```
Map<String, String> byNameMap = remap(persons, (key, val) -> key + ":" + val.getName());
```

Answer (score 1):

Since Java 9 you can also do:

```
Entry<String, String> entry = Map.entry("a", "b");
```

In your Map it would be used like this:

```
Map<String, String> byNameMap = people.entrySet()
  .stream()
  .map(entry -> Map.entry(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().getName()))
  .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue);
```