# Java 8 Lambda, filter HashMap, cannot resolve method

Tags: java, lambda

I'm kinda new to Java 8's new features. I am learning how to filter a map by entries. I have looked at [this tutorial](http://www.leveluplunch.com/java/examples/filter-map-by-value/) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22840170/in-java-8-functional-style-how-can-i-map-the-values-over-a-java-util-map) for my problem, but I am unable to solve.

```
@Test
public void testSomething() throws Exception {
    HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("1", 1);
    map.put("2", 2);
    map = map.entrySet()
            .parallelStream()
            .filter(e -> e.getValue()>1)
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(e->e.getKey(), e->e.getValue()));
}
```

However, my IDE (IntelliJ) says "Cannot resolve method 'getKey()'", thus unable to complile:
[image]

Neither does this help:
[image]
Can anyone help me to solve this issue? 
Thanks.

Comment: if i may ask.. what is **e** exactly.. dont see it declared anywhere..

Comment: @tobias_k, should not a problem regarding generics. It should work according to this http://www.leveluplunch.com/java/examples/filter-map-by-value/

Comment: @FlorentBayle adding casting (HashMap<String, Integer>) helps!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The message is misleading but your code does not compile for another reason: `collect` returns a `Map<String, Integer>` not a `HashMap`.

If you use

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
```

it should work as expected (also make sure you have all the relevant imports).

Comment: Apparently it will take *some* time for the compiler to get smart enough about the true cause of an error. Quite frustrating at the moment...

Comment: If we down cast what is returned by .collect by (HashMap<String, Integer>), it appears to work. But is there any issue regarding casting?

Comment: I for one always prefer to generate data structures from the interfaces, List, Map e.t.c.

Comment: @Daniel The collector does not give you any guarantee on the type returned - so it may work now and break in the future.

Comment: `The message is misleading`: 
This saved my day. I was using `toSet()`, where I should have used `toList()`. The message is indeed very confusing.

Answer (score 5):

Your are returning Map not hashMap so you need to change `map` type to `java.util.Map`. Moreover you can use **method reference** rather then calling getKey, getValue. E.g.

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("1", 1);
        map.put("2", 2);
        map = map.entrySet()
                .parallelStream()
                .filter(e -> e.getValue() > 1)
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

You could solve it by using some intellij help as well for e.g. if you press `ctrl+alt+v` in front of

```
new HashMap<>();
            map.put("1", 1);
            map.put("2", 2);
            map = map.entrySet()
                    .parallelStream()
                    .filter(e -> e.getValue() > 1)
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

The variable created by intellij will be of exact type and you will get.

```
Map<String, Integer> collect = map.entrySet()
        .parallelStream()
        .filter(e -> e.getValue() > 1)
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

Comment: ctrl+alt+v is awesome