# org.json.JSONObject cannot be cast to java.util.Map

Tags: java, android, json

Casting Map to a JSONObject for android app. Builds but crashes on run-time. Looked in the Logcat and got error:

> org.json.JSONObject cannot be cast to java.util.Map

Here is the section related:

```
JSONObject item = new JSONObject(data);
Map product = ((Map)item.get("product"));
```

It's specifically the second line that's making it crash. I commented out code until un-commenting this line caused the crash.

The JSON it's linked to is [here](https://world.openfoodfacts.org/api/v0/product/737628064502.json).

Unmapping the JSONObject gives this error:

> Incompatible types.
>
> Required:  java.util.Map<, >
>
> Found:     java.lang.Object

More extensive code view:

```
        TextView parsed = findViewById(R.id.jsonParse);
        String barcodeNum = result.getText();
        String productName = "";

        try {
            URL url = new URL("https://world.openfoodfacts.org/api/v0/product/" + barcodeNum + ".json");
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String data = "";
            String line = "";

            while (line != null){
                line = bufferedReader.readLine();
                data = data + line;
            }


            JSONObject item = new JSONObject(data);
            final JSONObject product = item.getJSONObject("product");
            final Map<String, Object> map =
                    product.keySet()
                            .stream()
                            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                                    Function.identity(),
                                    product::get
                            ));
```

Comment: What is data and why Map? @George Hanlon

Comment: @MS90 data is a parsed String of the json contents.

Answer (score 2):

```
JSONObject#get
```

isn't going to return a `Map`. Instead it will return another `JSONObject`, which describes the nested `product` property.

You'll see, indeed, it can be casted to it

```
final JSONObject product = (JSONObject) item.get("product");
```

---

What you can do is

```
final JSONObject product = item.getJSONObject("product");
final Map<String, Object> objectMap = product.toMap();
```

---

On old versions of JSON-Java, which don't offer the `toMap` method, what you can do is

```
final JSONObject product = item.getJSONObject("product");
final Map<String, Object> map =
        product.keySet()
               .stream()
               .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                       Function.identity(),
                       product::get
               ));
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Think I'm being stupid here but using .toMap() gives me: Cannot resolve method 'toMap()'  Tried looking here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27841225/java-8-lambda-filter-hashmap-cannot-resolve-method

Comment: @GeorgeHanlon could you tell me which version of JSON-Java you're using? The toMap method is pretty recent, and you might not be able to use it on old releases.

Comment: @GeorgeHanlon updated with a way to obtain a Map when using old versions of JSON-Java.

Comment: hm that's strange, the old version of JSON-Java method " Cannot resolve symbol 'jsonObject' ". Same with .keySet(). And yet it doesn't seem to have the .toMap() method. Apologies for being a novice, but how would I check the version of JSON-Java? Thanks for the help - really appreciated.

Comment: @GeorgeHanlon can you do a screenshot of the available methods?

Comment: @GeorgeHanlon thanks, but that's of Map, not of JSONObject ;) I need JSONObject.

Comment: @GeorgeHanlon okay... Understood. Copy-paste my snippet at the bottom again. Then look at the differences here https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55426156/revisions and you'll understand

Comment: Ah the first line from the bottom is now working. Still having issues with ".keySet()" method not found though.

Comment: @GeorgeHanlon ok, I need a screenshot of the JSONObject methods.

Comment: Ok screenshot of methods: [1](https://i.gyazo.com/0c6e5936fe3d1a4782d6743eeb00313c.png) [2](https://i.gyazo.com/0a93df600252955b89deaa5fccc7a2d6.png) [3](https://i.gyazo.com/64228345117e20af40f720a74dc3b2f7.png) [4](https://i.gyazo.com/1102a06a315049a2a5ac85e94cb84639.png)

Comment: @GeorgeHanlon on screen 3, you can see you have a keySet method. So you must be doing something wrong. Can you post your current code?

Comment: Updated the original post with a more extensive view of the code.

Comment: @GeorgeHanlon and that doesn't work because it tells you there is no "keySet" method? Seems impossible.

Comment: Yeah, I tried doing a clean build too. Might get my friend to pull from my branch and see if he has the same issue in case it is something local. Thank you for your help to far - it is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @GeorgeHanlon it is really strange. Maybe do a screenshot of the error. I'm curious now. Ultimately, what I posted works perfectly, don't worry about that.

Comment: Screenshots [1](https://i.gyazo.com/e885e5f393e13ee380c115cbe376f3da.png) and [2](https://i.gyazo.com/ceddffa04ab85f4cb2a34a20f8a7687b.png)

Comment: @GeorgeHanlon thanks! How are you linking the JSON-Java library? Using Gradle?

Comment: Yes I have `implementation 'com.cedarsoftware:json-io:4.10.1'`

Comment: @GeorgeHanlon you're not using that library here. You need to look for "org.json".

Comment: Huh, tried adding `implementation 'org.json:json:20180813'` and `implementation files('json-simple-1.1.jar')` but still the same results.

Comment: @GeorgeHanlon Remove implementation files. And reimport. Anyway i think you messed up the project