# How to change Map<String, List<Integer>> to Map<String, Integer>

Tags: java

I have created a `Map<String, List<Integer>>` to store multiple values against a key. Now I want to sum all those values in List and change the type to `Map<String, Integer>`. How can I do this with Java 8 streams & Is it possible to do the same without it

Comment: Of course it's possible to do it without streams. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using streams, how can I map the values in a HashMap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22840170/using-streams-how-can-i-map-the-values-in-a-hashmap)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to do it without streams:

```
Map<String, Integer> resultMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
sourceMap.forEach((k, v) -> v.forEach(e -> resultMap.merge(k, e, Integer::sum)));
```

This uses the [`Map.merge`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-) method to perform the reduction.

The version with streams would be as follows:

```
Map<String, Integer> resultMap = sourceMap.entrySet().stream()
    .flatMap(e -> e.getValue().stream()
        .map(v -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(e.getKey(), v)))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        e -> e.getKey(),
        e -> e.getValue(),
        Integer::sum));
```

Comment: sourceMap.forEach((k, v) -> resultMap.merge(k, v, Integer::sum)); is giving error. I found sourceMap.forEach((k,v)-> resultMap.put(k,v.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum())); can work instead.

Comment: @soumya-kole Thanks for pointing out the error! I'll include the fix

Answer (score 1):

Here you go buddy

```
    Map<String,Integer> output new HashMap<String,Integer>();
    Map<String,List<Integer>> gfg = new HashMap<String,List<Integer>>(); 
    for (Map.Entry<String,List<Integer>> entry : gfg.entrySet()){  
         Integer int = 0;
         for (Integer i :entry.getValue()){
              int+=i
         }
         output.put(entry.getKey(),Integer.toString(int));
         System.out.println("Key = " + entry.getKey() + 
                           ", Value = " + entry.getValue()); 
    }
```

This is a more open method for room for minor changes

Comment: I get the idea of this...it works as well, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

@fps already post a good answer, You can try  this simple way using stream

```
Map<String, Integer> resultMap = 
        sourceMap.entrySet()
                 .stream()
                 .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey(), 
                                    e -> e.getValue().stream().mapToInt(i -> i).sum()));
```